# In Windows batch, how do I copy multiple folders selected by a naming criteria with robocopy?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, backup, robocopy

I would like to use robocopy to copy multiple directories based on a similarity in the folder names' first few characters. **How do I pick out certain directory names (perhaps with regular expressions?) and a loop of some sort so that I can avoid this horrible redundancy in copying the directories and their contents?** The programmer in me dies a little bit each time I copy and paste these 3 lines and modify the folder names manually.

```
set "src=C:\Users\MyName\Photos\2015-10-25"
set "dest=E:\ExtBackup\2015-photo-backup\2015-10-25"
robocopy "%src%" "%dest%"
set "src=C:\Users\MyName\Photos\2015-10-13"
set "dest=E:\ExtBackup\2015-photo-backup\2015-10-13"
robocopy "%src%" "%dest%"
set "src=C:\Users\MyName\Photos\2015-10-02"
set "dest=E:\ExtBackup\2015-photo-backup\2015-10-02"
robocopy "%src%" "%dest%"
```

Rules

- I'm not copying all the directories in Photos, so a way to pick out the directory name is needed
- The source directory name must be copied too. That's why I'm repeating the source dir name in the destination
- must use `robocopy`
- I wish to learn batch and avoid redundant scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "src=C:\Users\MyName\Photos"
set "dest=E:\ExtBackup\2015-photo-backup\"

rem List every folders (/ad) that start with 2015-10 by using *
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%src%\2015-10*"') do (
  rem copy each folder to destination
  echo robocopy "%%~a" "%dest%"
)
```

Do not forget to remove `echo` if the tests are OK.
Note: if you need to copy subdir, move or anything else related to robocopy see this [page](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: As currently written, you still need to change 3 lines (at least once per month). I'd prefer a solution with parameters, something like `mybatch [yyyy [mm [dd]]]`. Then, if `dd` not supplied => take `*`; if `mm` not supplied => take current (or previous?) month or `??`; if `yyyy` not supplied => take current year. And `%%~a` modifier works only if command extensions are enabled (use `SETLOCAL enableextensions` as it is not automatic).

Comment: Could have used `FOR /D` as well.